# Extract active IDs on rolling window in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, rolling-computation

I have a time-ordered table with dates (yyyy-mm-dd), IDs and values.
What I want to do : Create a table with one row per date, and for every date the value is all the IDs with at least one occurrence in the past 5 days.

So for the example below :

| Timestamp | ID | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2015-01-01 | a | 1.05 |
| 2015-01-01 | b | 2.02 |
| 2015-01-01 | c | 1.1 |
| 2015-01-02 | b | 3.4 |
| 2015-01-02 | d | 10 |
| 2015-01-03 | b | 6.7 |
| 2015-01-04 | d | 7.8 |
| 2015-01-05 | d | 11 |
| 2015-01-05 | b | 0.5 |
| 2015-01-06 | e | 15 |
| 2015-01-07 | a | 12 |
| 2015-01-08 | c | 13 |

The output would be either

| Timestamp | active_IDs |
| --- | --- |
| 2015-01-06 | `['a','b','c','d']` |
| 2015-01-07 | `['b','d','e']` |
| 2015-01-08 | `['b','d','e','a']` |

or

| Timestamp | active_IDs |
| --- | --- |
| 2015-01-06 | a |
| 2015-01-06 | b |
| 2015-01-06 | c |
| 2015-01-06 | d |
| 2015-01-07 | b |
| 2015-01-07 | d |
| 2015-01-07 | e |
| 2015-01-08 | b |
| 2015-01-08 | d |
| 2015-01-08 | e |
| 2015-01-08 | a |

I believe the second output would probably easier to use for joining afterwards.

In pandas, I think this could be achieved using

```
list(df.groupby('Timestamp')['ID'].rolling(window=5, closed='left'))
```

Unfortunately, I'm dealing with huge tables so pandas isn't an option here, and I'm a SQL/MySQL newbie.
Can anyone point me to SQL functions that would allow me to solve this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There may be better options, but you could try using [LAG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) to find the date 5 days ago. Then use [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) to identify and sort the "id" values, but first occurrence. Definitely profile the query to see how well it performs with a larger dataset.

```
WITH dateRanges AS (
  SELECT Timestamp AS EndDate
         , LAG(t.Timestamp, 5, NULL) 
               OVER(ORDER BY Timestamp ASC) AS StartDate
  FROM  ( SELECT Timestamp
          FROM   YourTable
          GROUP BY TimeStamp
        ) t   
)
, IdsByOccurence AS (
    SELECT r.EndDate
          , t.Id AS Active_Ids
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
               PARTITION BY r.EndDate, t.Id
               ORDER BY t.Timestamp
            ) AS OccurNum
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
               PARTITION BY r.EndDate
               ORDER BY t.Timestamp
          ) AS DateRowNum
     FROM   dateRanges r INNER JOIN YourTable t 
               ON t.Timestamp >= r.StartDate
               AND t.Timestamp < r.EndDate
     WHERE  r.StartDate IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT EndDate AS TimeStamp, Active_Ids
FROM   IdsByOccurence
WHERE  OccurNum = 1
ORDER BY EndDate, DateRowNum
```

**Results:**

> ```
> TimeStamp           | Active_Ids
> :------------------ | :---------
> 2015-01-06 00:00:00 | b         
> 2015-01-06 00:00:00 | c         
> 2015-01-06 00:00:00 | a         
> 2015-01-06 00:00:00 | d         
> 2015-01-07 00:00:00 | b         
> 2015-01-07 00:00:00 | d         
> 2015-01-07 00:00:00 | e         
> 2015-01-08 00:00:00 | b         
> 2015-01-08 00:00:00 | d         
> 2015-01-08 00:00:00 | e         
> 2015-01-08 00:00:00 | a
> ```